# What's the best way to distribute python command-line tools?

Tags: python, command-line, packaging

My current `setup.py` script works okay, but it installs `tvnamer.py` (the tool) as `tvnamer.py` into site-packages or somewhere similar..

Can I make `setup.py` install `tvnamer.py` as `tvnamer`, and/or is there a better way of installing command-line applications?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setup.py and adding file to /bin/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840182/setup-py-and-adding-file-to-bin)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try the `entry_points.console_scripts` parameter in the setup() call. As described in the [setuptools docs](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#automatic-script-creation), this should do what I think you want.

To reproduce here:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    # other arguments here...
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'foo = package.module:func',
            'bar = othermodule:somefunc',
        ],
    }
)
```

Comment: When I try this with Python 2.6 and 3.1, I get a message `UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'entry_points'`. So I guess it's not supported in the `distutils` that comes with Python (2.6 and 3.1). So, is it okay to use this option if we want to distribute on PyPI?

Comment: on Ubuntu 11.04, install python-setuptools. Make sure you setup.py is importing: 'from setuptools import setup'