# Deploying a python application with shared package

Tags: python, naming, package, conventions, deploying

I'm thinking how to arrange a deployed python application which will have a

1. Executable script located in /usr/bin/ which will provide a CLI to functionality implemented in
2. A library installed to wherever the current site-packages directory is.

Now, currently, I have the following directory structure in my sources:

```
foo.py
foo/
  __init__.py
  ...
```

which I guess is not the best way to do things. During development, everything works as expected, however when deployed, the "from foo import FooObject" code in foo.py seemingly attempts to import foo.py itself, which is not the behaviour I'm looking for.

So the question is what is the standard practice of orchestrating situations like this? One of the things I could think of is, when installing, rename foo.py to just foo, which stops it from importing itself, but that seems rather awkward...

Another part of the problem, I suppose, is that it's a naming challenge. Perhaps call the executable script foo-bin.py?

Comment: Isn't this the same as.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893/whats-the-best-way-to-distribute-python-command-line-tools

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This article](http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/39794.html) is pretty good, and shows you a good way to do it. The second item from the *Do* list answers your question.

*shameless copy paste:*

> ## Filesystem structure of a Python project
>
> *by [Jp Calderone](http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/profile)*
>
> **Do:**
>
> - name the directory something related to your project. For example, if your
>     project is named "Twisted", name the
>     top-level directory for its source
>     files `Twisted`. When you do releases,
>     you should include a version number
>     suffix: `Twisted-2.5`.
> - create a directory `Twisted/bin` and put your executables there, if you
>     have any. Don't give them a `.py`
>     extension, even if they are Python
>     source files. Don't put any code in
>     them except an import of and call to a
>     main function defined somewhere else
>     in your projects.
> - If your project is expressable as a single Python source file, then put it
>     into the directory and name it
>     something related to your project. For
>     example, `Twisted/twisted.py`. If you
>     need multiple source files, create a
>     package instead (`Twisted/twisted/`,
>     with an empty
>     `Twisted/twisted/__init__.py`) and place
>     your source files in it. For example,
>     `Twisted/twisted/internet.py`.
> - put your unit tests in a sub-package of your package (note - this means
>     that the single Python source file
>     option above was a trick - you always
>     need at least one other file for your
>     unit tests). For example,
>     `Twisted/twisted/test/`. Of course, make
>     it a package with
>     `Twisted/twisted/test/__init__.py`.
>     Place tests in files like
>     `Twisted/twisted/test/test_internet.py`.
> - add `Twisted/README` and `Twisted/setup.py` to explain and
>     install your software, respectively,
>     if you're feeling nice.
>
> **Don't:**
>
> - put your source in a directory called `src` or `lib`. This makes it hard
>     to run without installing.
> - put your tests outside of your Python package. This makes it hard to
>     run the tests against an installed
>     version.
> - create a package that only has a `__init__.py` and then put all your code into `__init__.py`. Just make a module
>     instead of a package, it's simpler.
> - try to come up with magical hacks to make Python able to import your module
>     or package without having the user add
>     the directory containing it to their
>     import path (either via `PYTHONPATH` or
>     some other mechanism). You will not
>     correctly handle all cases and users
>     will get angry at you when your
>     software doesn't work in their
>     environment.

Comment: This is good stuff, and I will be using it, but I also would like to work on Windows. Removing the '.py' extension from Python files seems less workable there. Am I missing something? Would your install process put them back, or wrap them, or something?

Answer (score 2):

[Distutils](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/dist/dist.html) supports installing modules, packages, and scripts. If you create a distutils `setup.py` which refers to `foo` as a package and `foo.py` as a script, then `foo.py` should get installed to `/usr/local/bin` or whatever the appropriate script install path is on the target OS, and the `foo` package should get installed to the `site_packages` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the executable just `foo`, not `foo.py`, then attempts to import foo will not use it.

As for naming it properly: this is difficult to answer in the abstract; we would need to know what specifically it does. For example, if it configures and controls, calling it -config or ctl might be appropriate. If it is a shell API for the library, it should have the same name as the library.

Comment: The directory is named foo, so that obviously won't work. The next best thing is bin/foo, but then you have to twiddle with sys.path to find your package dir.

Answer (score 0):

Your CLI module is one thing, the package that supports it is another thing.  Don't confuse the names withe module `foo` (in a file `foo.py`) and the package `foo` (in a directory `foo` with a file `__init__.py`).

You have two things named `foo`: a module and a package.  What else do you want to name `foo`?  A class?  A function?  A variable?

Pick a distinctive name for the foo module or the foo package.  `foolib`, for example, is a popular package name.