# How can I use setuptools to generate a console_scripts entry point which calls `python -m mypackage`?

Tags: python, deployment, setuptools, pep

I am trying to be a good Pythonista and following [PEP 338](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/) for my package I plan on deploying.

I am also trying to generate my executable scripts upon `python setuptools install` using setuptools `entry_points{'console_scripts': ... }` options.

How can I use entry_points to generate a binary that calls `python -m mypackage` (and passes *args, **kwargs) ?

Here are a few attempts I have made with no success:

```
setuptools(
...
```

(1)

```
entry_points=
       {'console_scripts': ['mypkg=mypkg.__main__'],},
```

(2)

```
entry_points=
       {'console_scripts': ['mypkg=mypkg.main'],},
```

(3)

```
entry_points=
       {'console_scripts': ['mypkg=python -m mypkg'],},
```

Primary resources I have been using:

- http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/
- http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/command-line-scripts.html
- http://blog.habnab.it/blog/2013/07/21/python-packages-and-you/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> How can I use entry_points to generate a binary that calls python -m mypackage (and passes *args, **kwargs) ?

I think this is the wrong way to look at the problem. You don't want your script to call `python -m mypackage`, but you want the script to have the same entry point as `python -m mypackage`

Consider this simple example:

```
script_proj/
├── script_proj
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __main__.py
└── setup.py
```

and the minimalistic setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="script_proj",
    packages=["script_proj"],
    entry_points = {
        "console_scripts": [
            "myscript = script_proj.__main__:main",
        ]
    }
)
```

`__main__.py` is a dummy module and contains the `main` method.

```
def main():
    print("Hello world!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

After installing, you have the executable `myscript`, which calls the `main` method in `__main__.py`.
In this package design `python -m script_proj` also calls the same `main` method.

Comment: This works for me, however when calling `myscript`, my main() function is called twice. My main function only contains a `print("Success!")` statement, and I get the output twice.

Comment: To add to this, calling `python -m script_proj` will only produce 1 output

Comment: @rm-rf_, it seems to work for me. `myscript` prints the same as `python -m script_proj` only one `Hello world!`... hmm

Comment: @rm-rf_, did you use `if __name__ == "__main__":` to make sure your main is only called, when `__main__.py`is called as a script, and not as a module?

Comment: Got it! Just needed the if `__name__ == "__main__"` in __main__.py. Silly mistake. Thanks so much.

Comment: For those using a `setup.cfg`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48891252/3388962) for how to set entry points.