# How to make python module executable?

Tags: python, pip

When using pip, we can download and use python module.

One of them is like python file, like "pip install validators" and then we can import validators.

One of them is like executable. like "pip install pyinstaller" and "pyinstaller 
something.py".

I am now writing a python module XYZ. How to make my module executable after "pip install XYZ" just like XYZ?

Comment: Potentially helpful question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27784271/3901060

Comment: I would suggest reading [this article](http://marthall.github.io/blog/how-to-package-a-python-app/). It looks like it describes what you're asking for.