# How to set up entry_points in setup.cfg

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, setuptools

I am moving my config from setup.py to setup.cfg and having issues setting up the `entry_points` parameter. At the moment I am using a hybrid approach which works, however, I would like to move the `entry_points` to setup.cfg.

From

```
def setup_package():
    setup(version=get_version(),
          entry_points={'console_scripts':['app=my_package.app.run:cli'],})
```

to

```
[metadata]
name = my-package
description = my-package
license = unlicensed
long-description = README.md
platforms = any
classifiers =
  Programming Language :: Python

[options]
zip_safe = False
packages = my_package,  my_package.app
include_package_data = True
package_dir =
  = .
tests_require = pytest; pytest-cov

[entry_points]
console_scripts =
  my-package = my_package.app.run:cli
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The section must be `[options.entry_points]`. See an example at https://github.com/github/octodns/blob/4b44ab14b1f0a52f1051c67656d6e3dd6f0ba903/setup.cfg#L34

```
[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    octodns-compare = octodns.cmds.compare:main
    octodns-dump = octodns.cmds.dump:main
    octodns-report = octodns.cmds.report:main
    octodns-sync = octodns.cmds.sync:main
    octodns-validate = octodns.cmds.validate:main
```

Comment: This did not work for me. After I moved the entry-script to this, changed the name to "foobar", the console script foobar was not available.

Comment: how about a simple `scripts = bin/compare.py` ?

Comment: @qrtLs There is a big difference between `scripts` and `entry_points`. See https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation

Answer (score 1):

With python 3.6 and setuptools 39.0.1, i had like you to move entry points from `.py` to `.cfg`.

My `setup.py`, focused on the entry points declaration:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    entry_points={
        'pytest11': [
            'mytest = mytest.plugin',
        ],
    },
)
```

I ended up with this working `setup.cfg`:

```
... # other standard declarations

[options.entry_points]
pytest11 =
    mytest = mytest.plugin
```