# Structure of package that can also be run as command line script

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, argparse, python-packaging

I have written a package with [the 'standard' minimal structure](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html). It looks like this:

```
my_package/
    my_package/
        __init__.py
    setup.py
```

`__init__.py` contains a class and as such can simply be imported and used as one would expect.

However, the code really lends itself to be used in a command-line-way, e.g.

```
python my_package --arg1 "I like bananas."
```

At first, I just had an `if __name__ == '__main__'` check in `__init__` which would then use `argparse`. This *works* but it isn't pretty, because it would mean that you'd call it from the command line like so:

```
python my_package/__init__.py --arg1 "I like bananas."
```

From what I read, this is where a `__main__.py` file comes in which would be executed as the default script inside a folder (similar to a `index.html` file on a website). The idea I have is to then simply import `__init__.py`, run argparse and feed the arguments to the class constructor. Like so:

```
import argparse
from __init__ import MyClass

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--arg1", help="Some dummy value")

args = parser.parse_args()
my_class = MyClass(**vars(args))
my_class.do_stuff()
```

Is this how similar packages ought to be structured, or is there a better way?

---

The above works *but* PyCharm tells me that in `__main__.py` `__init__` is an unresolved reference. Same for `MyClass` on that import line. When I use `.__init__` instead (with a dot) the warning goes away but then the code doesn't work anymore, giving me a `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

Comment: `from __init__ import MyClass` -> `from mypackage import MyClass`? Why are you trying to import init directly? Then, call it with `python -m mypackage --arg=whatever`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I want to suggest a different structure to you:

```
my_package/
    my_package/
        __init__.py
        cli_scripts.py
    setup.py
```

Let's assume your `__init__.py` looks like this (as a side note, I'd recommend moving the classes defined in there to a separate file, and then simply importing that file in the `__init__`):

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, a)
        self.a = a

    def __call__(self):
        print(self.a)
```

Now there is an additional file inside the package that utilizes the stuff you implemented in the package, let's call it `cli_scripts.py`:

```
import argparse

from my_package import Test


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("a", type=int, help="Just an example argument")
    return parser.parse_args()

def demonstration():
    args = parse_args()
    t = Test(a=args.a)
    t()
```

My suggestion now is to utilize the [console_scripts entry point](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point) inside `setup.py`, which could now look something like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='testpy',
    version='0.1',
    description='Just an example',
    author='RunOrVeith',
    author_email='xyz@mailinator.com',
    packages=["my_package"],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": ["mypkg=my_package.cli_scripts:demonstration"]},
    install_requires=[],
)
```

Now when you run `pip install .` inside the top-level `my_package` folder, your package will be installed. The `entry_points` automatically generate an executable for you, that you can now call with the name you gave it inside `setup.py`, in this example `mypkg`. This means you can now run

`mypkg 5`
and this will call `demonstration()`.

This way:

- you do not need to handle any `__main__` files
- you can give your script a meaningful name
- you don't need to care whether your script is executable, or specify to run the script with `python`
- you can have as many of these as you want inside the list `entry_points`
- it forces you to write functions that you could also call from other modules,
  instead of the `__main__`

I think this is pretty clean. 
You can read more about `entry_points` in [this blog](https://www.eflglobal.com/setuptools-entry-points/), it has more functionalities!
If you want to use code specified in `__main__` instead of this `cli_scripts` approach, you can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784271/how-can-i-use-setuptools-to-generate-a-console-scripts-entry-point-which-calls).