# How to use setuptools to install a python script for windows command line?

Tags: python, windows, pip, setuptools

I have been working on a python command line application that I want to be runnable from command prompt on windows as well as the terminal in OSX and on linux. 
My goal is to make a pip module that allows my application to be useable on the command line once installed.

Using setup tools I was able to get the script to run on both linux and OSX with the command:

`youtube-song-downloader <search query>`

after running:

```
python setup.py install
```

which would also work directly after installing through pip

But when I try to use the same setup.py on windows, it is unable to recognize the command (likely that it is not added to the path)

How would I go about making my script useable on the windows command line from a pip install or setup.py install?

My setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup

setup(name='youtube-song-downloader',
      version='0.1',
      description='A program used to search and download songs from Youtube.',
      url='https://github.com/dszopa/youtube-song-downloader',
      author='Daniel Szopa',
      author_email='dszopa@iastate.edu',
      license='MIT',
      install_requires=[
          'youtube_dl',
          'google-api-python-client',
          'pytest',
      ],
      packages=['ytsdl'],
      scripts=['bin/youtube-song-downloader'],
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False)
```

My program structure is as follows:

```
+ bin
  - youtube-song-downloader
+ tests
+ ytsdl
  - songDownloader.py
  - settings.json
- .gitignore
- MANIFEST.in
- requirements.txt
- setup.py
```

If you have any further questions about my code my github repo is [here](https://github.com/dszopa/youtube-song-downloader)

---

### Edit 1

I added this to my setup.py

```
  entrypoints={
    'console_scripts': [
      'youtube-song-downloader = ytsdl:main',
    ]
  },
```

I also created a `__main__.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os
import ytsdl

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()

def main():
  #script from bin/youtube-song-downloader
```

and also added `__main__` to my `__init__` with
`from .ytsdl import __main__`

Im pretty unsure if I'm headed in the right direction, the program compiled but had no luck with the same command

Comment: The best thing to do for Windows is to set things up so people can run your script via `py [-X[.Y[-32]]] -m ytsdl`. To do this, add a `__main__.py` script to the package. You can have the script run a `ytsdl.main` function. This `main` function is also the entry point for [automatic script creation](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation). This will create scripts and EXEs on Windows. The "Scripts" directory isn't normally on the search `PATH`, but it will be for an active `venv` environment.

Comment: So would I basically want to put what I have in my youtube-song-downloader script into a main function in ytsdl and then set and entrypoint for it? If so im a bit confused as to what I would want for the syntax of my `package.module:method` part of the console_script

Comment: Put `main` in your `__init__.py`. Then the console-script entry point is `'youtube-song-downloader=ytsdl:main'`. Don't forget the `__main__.py` script for use with `py -m ytsdl` or `python -m ytsdl`.

Comment: It's `entry_points`, not `entrypoints`. The `main` function goes in the `__init__.py` module. `__main__.py` imports `ytsdl` and calls `ytsdl.main()`.

Comment: This article has a good overall explanation for how to package a command-line Python package: https://gehrcke.de/2014/02/distributing-a-python-command-line-application/   There is also an example repo:  https://github.com/jgehrcke/python-cmdline-bootstrap   Both were very helpful for me.

Comment: Here's an updated link: [automatic script creation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation), as the old one is dead at this moment.

Answer (score -1):

1. When developing, make sure you have a shebang containing "python" (`#!/usr/bin/env python`) in the name in all script files that should be later directly executed by the user, even later the path is different on target platforms (https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts)
2. Put all user-callable scripts to the `scripts` argument of the `setup` call in your `setup.py` as you showed (although I would not omit the `.py` extension).

Once installed on the target platform with `pip install` the target shebang is replaced by a suitable one and the scripts are put in a path where they are found.

If the user has setup Python correctly, she should be able to use them without prepending `python`.

For Windows, for example, the [Python Launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) (`py.exe`) should be associated with `.py` files, that's optionally offered during Python setup. To omit the `.py` extension, `.py` can be in the `PATHEXT` environment variable.