# Python script installation fails on windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, shutil

I'm trying to deploy a larger python project which includes a script on
windows. Installation works fine on UNIX, but on windows it seems
impossible to get the script running. I've created a minimal example on
[GitHub](https://github.com/maltekliemann/hello-world/tree/broken) to demonstrate
the problem.

When running `pip install .`, the script is installed to `C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\hello-world`. The directory is contained in the
`PATH`. My user has read & execute permissions. The hashbang of
`hello-world` is replaced with `#!c:\program files\python39\python.exe`,
which also seems correct. However, running `hello-world` in the console
yields the following error:

```
C:\Users\malte>hello-world
'hello-world' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I expected this to work. Why doesn't it? How can I fix this?

I've tried some things, and noticed another strange behavior in this
context. Running `shutil.which('hello-world')` returns `None`. If I
rename `hello-world` to `hello-world.exe`, then calling `hello-world`
results in a strange error, most likely because windows
now thinks the script is a binary. That's fine. Except that now
`shutil.which('hello-world')`
returns `'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\Scripts\\hello-world.EXE'`. Why?

## Update

The `master` branch of the respository now contains a solution that works cross-platform, which I learned from here: https://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/installing_scripts.html.

It's not exactly clear to me, but the following paragraph from the Python documentation seems to state that a script with a hashbang line *must have an extension associated with the python launcher* in order for windows to recognize it: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#from-a-script
In other words, it appears that my assumption that using the `scripts` parameter of `setuptools.setup` works cross-platform is subject to some conditions which are hidden somewhere in the python documentation.

Comment: `hashbang` the what?

Comment: @SuperStew https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix) :)

Comment: What if you name your file hello-world.py and execute it with the extension? I think that if no extension is present, windows cmd assumes it would be .exe - that's why `shutil.which('hello-world')` searches for `hello-world.exe` in PATH, as you noticed

Comment: @h4z3 Then I rename to `hello-world.py`, install and then do `hello-world`, I get a "How do you want to open this file?" dialog. *sigh* The file extension really shouldn't matter. I expect `pip` to install the script in a way that makes it work under windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566376/how-to-use-setuptools-to-install-a-python-script-for-windows-command-line might be a related question