# How to create a installation package for a python program?

Tags: python, setuptools, installation-package

I have a python project in which I have a main script (main_script.py) that uses other python modules created by me also (IMAP_conn.py, SMTP_conn.py, MySQL.py and data.py). I want create a setup file or a installation package so that can install my modules and my main script.

I have tried using setuptools which is very helpfull but i can inly install each module one by one and then have to install the main script.

I expect to create a installation package or a setup.py file that installs all my own modules and then install the main script.

Comment: please provide the setuptools code you have so far (the `setup.py`)

Comment: _"I expect to create a installation package or a setup.py file that installs all my own modules and then install the main script"_ -- how is that different from what setuptools do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setup.py and adding file to /bin/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840182/setup-py-and-adding-file-to-bin)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/distributing/index.html

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-wheel%5D+create