# Add .py extension when installing scripts on Windows platforms

Tags: python, package

How can I configure `setup.py` to install scripts with a `.py` prefix on Windows platforms but without the prefix on all others? The problem I'm trying to solve is that [Windows requires a `.py` extension to recognize and execute Python scripts](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable).

I have a package set up like the following:

```
MyPackage
├── CHANGES
├── ...
├── scripts
│   └── myprogram
├── setup.py
└── mypackage
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── ...
    └── myprogram.py
```

In my setup.py file I declare `scripts/myprogram` as an installable script with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from setuptools import setup

...

setup(
    name='MyPackage',
    ...
    packages=['mypackage'],
    scripts=['scripts/myprogram'],
    ...
)
```

The `myprogram` script is just a thin wrapper that simply calls `mypackage.myprogram.main()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from mypackage import myprogram
myprogram.main()
```

On *nix platforms, this installs `myprogram` as an executable by the name of `myprogram`, which is what I desire, but on Windows, it also installs as `myprogram` in the `C:\PythonXX\Scripts` directory, and is thus not recognized on the command line. How can I get the setup script to install `myprogram` as `myprogram.py` on Windows, so that Windows recognizes the file type to make it executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: a keyword argument to `setup()` called called `entry_points` with a dictionary containing `'console_scripts'`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17933/38140) to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893/whats-the-best-way-to-distribute-python-command-line-tools).

The new `setup` call looks like this:

```
 setup(
    name='MyPackage',
    ...
    packages=['mypackage'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'myprogram = mypackage.myprogram:main'
        ]
    }
    ...
)
```

After making those changes I then deleted the `scripts` directory and the `myprogram` file from it.

Now when running the installer, distribute creates two files under `C:\PythonXX\Scripts`: `myprogram-script.py` and `myprogram.exe`. As a result, the user can now enter `myprogram` on the command line of either *nix or Windows platforms and always have it run the same program. Very handy!