# Running python modules installed with pip without -m flag

Tags: python, linux, pip

I was creating a Python program that I want to be able to call anywhere in my shell.

Suppose, for the sake of simplicity, that it is a `hello.py` program that output a "Hello World!" when called.

Sure, I can add `#!/usr/bin/python` to the first line, remove the `.py` extension and put it in some place in `$PATH`.

Then, I wished that other users could easily install it, so I was thinking about packaging this program and uploading it as a module to pip.

My question is: can I let people use it without having to type `$ python -m hello`, only calling `$ hello` instead? The only way I've been able to use python programs installed by pip until now is using `$ python -m program_name`.

Tried to search something about *"global installation in pip"* and *"using pip packages without m flag"* but didn't succeed.

Comment: [macos - How do I make a python script executable? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494758/how-do-i-make-a-python-script-executable/50468400#50468400)

Comment: [What's the best way to distribute python command-line tools? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893/whats-the-best-way-to-distribute-python-command-line-tools/17933#17933)